# How can we sync files between two branches in git?

Tags: git

I have forked a project with many branches. Two branches in particular interest me.

```
1.8.x
2.2.x
```

I have introduced a new file, 'newfile.source' and changes to a file 'existingfile.source' that exists in both branches. I want to synchronize the changes I make in newfile and existingfile between both branches.

The way I model this in my head is something like this:

```
commit -- commit -- commit -- commit -- commit -- commit -- commit -- 2.2.x
                            \
                             -- commit -- 1.8.x
```

I want to have a structure (branch but only consisting of the changes to existingfile and newfile) that I can make changes to and merge into 1.8.x and 2.2.x:

```
nothing -- custom_changes -- nothing
```

and then do something like:

```
git checkout 2.2.x
git merge custom_changes
git checkout 1.8.x
git merge custom_changes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just commit it to one branch (like usual). I would prefer the newer one (2.2.x) here. Then switch to the old branch (1.8.x) and "backport" the commit using [`cherry-pick`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-cherry-pick)