# How can sync some files between two branches in git?

Tags: git

I have problem with git and my repo.

First I write example

```
git checkout Proj1
# modify index.html
git commit -am "Modify Index.html"
git checkout Proj2
git show Proj1:index.html > index.html
git commit -am "Modify Index.html"
git checkout Proj1
```

This is my way to keep the same file content in two branches.
Of course I can use cherry-pick if the commit only contain the file I want to sync.
[How can we sync files between two branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483524/how-can-we-sync-files-between-two-branches-in-git)

Do you have any short solution for this problem.
Maybe some alias to write?
Where I can keep file with list of files to sync?

Comment: I would like still working on Proj1.

Comment: Sync. between branches in GIT is git merge. Any other way is not the git way.

Comment: I agree with @yorammi, however you can investigate [git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) and symbolic/hard link. Though you can end up in a mess. Cannot help you further since I will go for merge and I did not investigate worktree that much yet

Comment: That depends on the pattern of the changes you are making. If there is a set of the common files you mostly/always change in both branches, you possibly should have another branch (e.g. `common`), make the changes there, and then merge them to both Projs. For some cases using another repository or submodule is a better way.

Comment: @Frax create other branch to keep only this file is good move. But how write something clearly to use.

Comment: you can also use `git rebase`

Comment: @war1oc yes but i find way to modify in Proj1 and in magic way my changes will be sync with Proj2. For example only file who been in common branch (@Frax). But in this way i must start editing from common :(

Comment: You can make change on one branch (possibly with detached HEAD), cherry-pick it to `common`, then merge into both branches.

Comment: I think submodule containing common file(s) would solve your problem in the most 'gitish' way, but it would generate a lot of overhead. It may be worth to consider it, but probably just to check you don't really like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont care about history, then you can make a separate commit on branch 2 containing the file exactly as it looks like on the tip of the commit in Proj1:

```
git checkout Proj2
git checkout Proj1  -- index.html

git commit -am "Modify Index.html"
```

Essentially, this means to take the file EXACTLY as it looks in Proj1 branch.

`git checkout --` means that after the dash you provide a filename (or path). This can be useful, also if you want to change some files in your repository and preserve others.

Then, if you want, you can also reuse the commit message from the commit you made in Proj1 like this:

```
git checkout Proj2
git checkout Proj1  -- index.html

git commit -a -C Proj1
```

Git `commit -C` means to reuse the commit comment you already had.

From the [git documentation "git checkout"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-p--patchlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203):

> git checkout `[-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>`
>
> When 
>   or `--patch` are given, git checkout does not switch branches. It
>   updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or
>   from a named  (most often a commit).
>
> [...]
>
> git checkout with  or `--patch` is used to restore modified or
>   deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace
>   paths with the contents from a named  (most often a
>   commit-ish).

And from the [git documentation "git commit"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--Cltcommitgt)

> `git commit -C <commit>`
>
> `--reuse-message=<commit>`
>
> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the
>   authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the
>   commit.