# Adding a folder to a new branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I only have one branch, the main branch that contains all the code of my application.
In this code, I have my dist folder that is generated with the build of ViteJS.
I would like to create the gh-pages branch (well, I know how to do that) and move *only* the dist folder into it.
That way, I can use my production folder for deployment on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the straightforward approach?
Create a `gh-pages` branch, checkout to that branch, delete everything except `dist/` folder, and commit it.
If you want to keep `dist/` folder up to date with the main branch, that's a different problem.
If that's the case, what you should be asking is, [How can sync some files between two branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419916/how-can-sync-some-files-between-two-branches-in-git)